# New to E4 (Styling UI with css). Met problems on set css to a child composite

Tags: css, eclipse, rcp

I'm a beginner of E4 and i've added CSS to my RCP application. The common widgets work fine. 
I've heard of the E4 could use the components class name as the selector.
So i've written a child class named DateFilterComposite which is extended to Composite, and tried to add css to style this components. However it not woks. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

The code is

```
DateFilterComposite {
    background-color: rgb(227,230,235);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class names in CSS start with a dot:

```
.DateFilterComposite {
    background-color: rgb(227,230,235);
}
```

Comment: Tried add dot in front of the class name,but it not works either. I thought .xxx is self-define selector. i've written like --css: .test1 {background-color: red} & java code: parent.setData(CSSSWTConstants.CSS_CLASS_NAME_KEY, "test1");  This .test1 style works.

Comment: So what HTML is output for the component you are trying to style?

Comment: Not open a html, it's a similar UI like eclipse itself. actually it's a configured eclipse.  well i've written a simple Dialog class and create it's content with several simple components, trying to test the E4 new features.

Comment: I've configured a composite which contained a label and a combo. And i'd like to use this component somewhere else no need to re-write the same code every time. but met problems on style it with css.  here's code of my component :  public class DateFilterComposite extends Composite
{
    ...
    public DateFilterComposite(Composite parent, int style, boolean showSearchRun)
    {
        super(parent, style);
        ...
        Label test1 = new Label(this, SWT.NONE);
        ...
        Combo = new Combo(this, SWT.READ_ONLY);
        ...

Comment: @user1047051 could you add your component code in your question, it will be easier for us to read.  Thanx.